# Closing file before renaming it

Tags: python, for-loop, permissions, file-rename

I am trying to read multiple CSV files in python, but before reading them I need to remove the spaces from their filenames. However, I encountered a `PermissionError`, which I think is related to closing the files.

My question is: How can I close the files in the `for` loop I created for the file list?

Basically, what I have is:

```
import glob
import os
from os.path import join as filejoin

directory = 'C:\\Users\\Downloads\\Test-Folders\\'
filepath = glob.glob(filejoin(directory,'*csv'))

ls = []
for filename in filepath:
    ls.append(os.rename(filename, filename.replace(" ", "-")))
```

The error I am having is  related to the following line: `ls.append(os.rename(filename, filename.replace(" ", "-")))`.

**Error**: `PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`.

Comment: You want to rename the files just because they have white `spaces`s in their names? Because you do not need to rename the files just because they have `space`s in their names in order to read them.

Comment: `os.rename()` doesn't return anything, so `ls` would just become a list of `None` items.

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of spaces in the filenames in the first place?

Comment: Your code doesn't open any files, so the error message is referring to files some other program has open. You can't close those.

Comment: The error may be because you have one of the files open, e.g. in a text editor or similar; exactly as it says in the error message. Nothing to do then with your program (which does have other issues, as pointed out above).

Comment: A clue as to why what @9769953 is saying is true is this part  the error message "...because it is being used by ***another*** process".